# Is there any way to access parameter or method of object with in Linklist that is for every object

Tags: c#, data-structures, xna

I am working on trees and I want to access object parameters, methods in `linlinkilist->Node->object->object` but couldn't do it.

What I am  trying to do is put collection group of object in tree, and search this object

So Linked List have 2 kind of objects parent and child and these objects construct get  another object, I am trying to search and find this `collisionObject` but I could not access it

I try to use list.head.data. but I couldn't success. I don't want to change Linked List data parameter as `CollisionObject` class because I want to use this Linked List for every other object normally I do parameter  that I want to use, as public or get;set; to access object within another object like list.head.data its stuck here; I could not access parameters or methods in data and also object with in data

```
public class Child
{
    private CollisonObject colobj;     
    public Child(CollisonObject c) { this.colobj = c;   }
    public Child(ref CollisonObject o) { this.refcolobj = o; }
    public void draw(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        colobj.draw(sb);   
    }    
}

public class Parent
{

    CollisonObject pcolobj;

    private LinkList list = new LinkList();
    public Parent(CollisonObject o) { this.pcolobj = o; }
    public void RenderPanel(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Child Control for Panel(" + Name + ")  Render start");

        foreach (Object item in ChildControls)
        {
            Parent objPanel = item as Parent;

            if (objPanel == null)
            {
                Child objTextbpx = item as Child;
                if (objTextbpx == null)
                { break; }
                objTextbpx.draw(sb);

            }
            else
            {
                objPanel.draw(sb);
                objPanel.RenderPanel(sb);

            }

        }
        //  Console.WriteLine("Child Control for Panel(" + Name + ")  Render End");
    }


    public void CreateChildControl(Object control)
    {


        list.AddtoBegining(control);

    } 

    public void DeleteChildControl(Object control)
    {
        ChildControls.Remove(control);
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        pcolobj.draw(sb);

    }
    public Object Search(object o)
    {     CollisonObject co = (CollisonObject)o;
              co = (CollisonObject)list.head.data;
               ChildControls.Remove(co.Name);

       return o;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using generics? That would be the obvious approach here. Also, your `ref` parameter really doesn't need to be `ref` - I suspect you may have misunderstood what `ref` means. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: İnstructer said you shold use your own Linked list; so i did one without generics,How can ı do thisin generic linkedlist?

Comment: Writing your own linked list doesn't mean you have to do it without generics...

Comment: Actually before normal linklist ı tried with generics and couldnt do it , i am not used to it; Is there any good tutorial for generics to access paramater of other object ; Thank you by the way answering my question wery quickly

Comment: I suggest you look for an MSDN tutorial, or get a good book. Generics is very important in C#, and worth learning about.